# Submitting image onChange

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I am trying to submit image onChange. However when I am trying to do it, server is saying that "file" is equal to null. Everything worked when I was sending image form submit.
[React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9XOV.png)

Comment: Add code as text. And please paste entire error message.

Comment: No offense, but I've never seen a worse example usage of useEffect than that in your code. What you're trying to achieve with it can be easily done with React event handlers.